# группировка по двум полям или запрос максимального количества

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

- ladder (это id товара из другой таблицы, в данной таблице типо
  разновидности)
- size(это размеры)
- lenght (это длина, одной длине соответствуют несколько размеров)

Мне необходимо получить для конкретного товара (максимальное количество размеров с одной длиной).

То есть

```
ladder size lenght
1 10 100
1 20 100
1 30 100
1 40 100
1 10 200
1 20 200
```

Я должен получить:

```
count
4
```

Если товар не один соответственно это будет таблица:

```
count
4
2
6
3
```

Таблица не большая максимум 200 записей будет
Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Comment: SELECT sum(*) From 'tablename' GROUP BY 'length'

Comment: Советую проиндексировать по length. Пока таблица небольшая.

Answer (score 1):

Подзапросом группируем по товарам и длине, считаем количество размеров у товаров. Результат группируем по товарам и выбираем максимальное количество.

```
SELECT
  ladder,
  max(size_count)
FROM (SELECT
        ladder,
        count(DISTINCT size) size_count
      FROM properties
      GROUP BY ladder, lenght) t
GROUP BY t.ladder;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726a3c/1)